# Count number of checkbox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have multiple individual checkbox's (50).

like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBirthDate" />
```

I need to know how many checkbox the user has selected (Count). If he has selected more than 3 i let him pass if not i present him an error message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**LINQ Approach**

You could take advantage of the querying capability of LINQ by using the [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method to grab all of your individual CheckBox Controls and then use a [`Count()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6z8Hs_K7MAhWDmoMKHeuEDPcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb338038(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGXJ-WPaymDb_qox1-IkLGUunptZA&sig2=4WcaIKhUc0QEqJMvUUH9-g&bvm=bv.120551593,d.amc) call to see how many were actually checked :

```
// Get the number of CheckBox Controls that are checked
var checkedBoxes = Form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(c => c.Checked);
// Determine if your specific criteria is met
if(checkedBoxes > 3)
{
      // You shall pass!
}
else 
{
      // None shall pass
}
```

You'll need to ensure that you have a reference to LINQ for this to work as well by including the following using statement :

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Iterative Looping Approach**

Alternatively, you could simply loop through and increment a count accordingly via a `foreach` loop as seen below :

```
// Store your count
var checkedBoxes = 0;
// Iterate through all of the Controls in your Form
foreach(Control c in Form.Controls)
{
    // If one of the Controls is a CheckBox and it is checked, then
    // increment your count
    if(c is CheckBox && (c as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        checkedBoxes++;
    }
}
```

**Example (with output)**

You can find [a GitHub Gist that fully reproduces this here](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/42aaf6e13827cb36d1c99b8ac182f881) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: It doesn't recognize me the OfType. Do i need some using?

Comment: Try adding a reference to LINQ via `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Do i need to replace something? because it doesn't count any checked checkbox

Comment: Try appending your `Controls` call with either `this.Controls` or `Form.Controls` to provide the proper context to access the CheckBoxes.

Comment: Hi, how can i know what checkboxes will be included to the LINQ approach?

Comment: @WTFZane If you are using the debugger, you can simply hover over the `checkedBoxes` variable within the first example to see which would be selected. By default, just using `Form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` will give you all the CheckBox controls from the form, however you can easily use a `Where()` clause to filter this down.

Comment: Working like a charm, it's so easy and convenient to use. Thanks Rion